# How to compute the curl of the electric field, experimentally?

Tags: experimental-physics, electric-circuits, maxwell-equations, electromagnetic-induction

In order to experimentally verify Faraday's law and express the curl of the induced electric field, is there any other way to compute the curl without directly working on the cross product (ie working through the cross products requires a lot attention to difficult measurements)... if there's any "other" way to calculate for curl that relies on some practical measurements... please help me out!

Comment: Could you elaborate more?

Comment: Is there any way you can calculate the curl using integrals.... instead of directly doing the cross products between the vector operator and the electric field!

Comment: So you want the expression of the curl of E with position dependence without having to compute the actual curl?

Comment: Yes.. u got that right! Actually an expression... that would also help me compute the curl as well... accept not with the cross the product of the vector operator and electric field

Comment: Just do the work. You will learn from it.

Comment: @my2cts I don't even know where to begin... on how to calculate the curl experimentally

Comment: @EPICTubeHD The question as it stands is confusing. You seem to ask how to calculate (not measure!) the curl without applying the curl operation. Whereas your last comment implies that you actually want to know a way to _measure_ the curl experimentally. Should your question maybe rephrased to "How can the curl of the electric field be measured experimentally" ?

Comment: YES I'll edit it. The thing is if I do use to calculate the curl using the curl operation... it's gonna be very hard experimentally to get the data for computing the curl. But if the curl to be written in some other form... that will allow me to get some measurable variable and therefore assign numbers to them, for the actual calculation.... then i get to find the curl experimentally. I am just merely searching for "other" ways to calculate the curl cuz using the vector operator will hard to calculate experimentally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The curl can be defined as the limit of flux passing through a loop $C$ ([see wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curl_(mathematics))). Let $\hat{n}$ be a vector of length one (the orientation of the loop, component of the curl in that direction), and $A$ be the area enclosed by the loop. Then

$$ \mathrm{curl}\vec{E}\cdot \hat{n} := \lim_{A\to 0}\frac{1}{|A|}\oint_{C} \vec{E}\cdot d\vec{s} \equiv \lim_{A\to 0}\frac{1}{|A|} \mathrm{EMF}_C$$ The integral on the right hand side is by definition the voltage along the loop.

To measure the curl experimentally, take a small piece of wire and form it into a loop with as small an area as possible (approximating the limit on the rhs). Bring the ends as close together as you can without them touching. Attach the ends of the loop to a voltmeter and measure the voltage between the terminals (evaluating the integral on the rhs), then divide by the area of the loop. Do this for three different orientations $\hat{n}$ at any point in space you'd like to measure the components of the curl in those directions.

Why three different directions? The curl is a vector. To determine it unambiguously you need its components in three linearly independent directions. For simplicity, choose three orthogonal axes - call them x,y,z - and measure in those directions. Then $\mathrm{curl}\vec{E} = (\mathrm{curl}\vec{E})_x \hat{x} + (\mathrm{curl}\vec{E})_y \hat{y} + (\mathrm{curl}\vec{E})_x \hat{z} $

That's how it works in theory. In practice (see Puk's comment below) you will probably have difficulty measuring anything because the effect is too small, unless the magnetic field is of high intensity or frequency. In that case, roll the wire to a coil and divide the measurement by the number of turns.

Comment: Thx for the comment I have been searching this for a while now.. "Do this for three different orientations ̂  at any point in space you'd like to measure the components of the curl in those directions." <-- here u say 3 different orientations ̂... could u please elaborate on this please!!!

Comment: I would call this integral the emf along the loop, not the voltage along the loop. Voltage is frequently (but not always) defined so that this integral is zero (which is Kirchhoff's voltage law). The scalar potential of electrodynamics is one such way to define voltage.

Comment: @Nephente.... also I would u add in the derivation for the curl of E expressed as a limit

Comment: @EPICTubeHD: I think Nephente means you need at least three such measurements to determine the curl, since each measurement gives you the component of the curl along the direction of the normal vector $\hat{n}$ to the loop. A simple set of directions would be any three orthogonal directions, which you may call $\hat{x}$, $\hat{y}$ and $\hat{z}$.

Comment: I would also add that unless the magnetic field is changing very fast or the loop area is very large, you would likely need to use a coil made of many turns to get a non-zero reading on the voltmeter.

Comment: @Puk Say say I solve the limit... by measuring the EMF... how does that corresponds to finding the components of the curl, with what measurements gives me the component of the curl

Comment: @EPICTubeHD Orient the loop such that its normal points in say x-direction. Measure the EMF and divide by the area of the loop. This gives you the curl in x-direction. The smaller the area, the better you approximate the curl (which is a purely local quantity). Repeat for the y- and z-direction.

Comment: After I get the curl for all x, y and z axis...how do I get the resultant curl, I mean is there a way to get the resultant curl (or like the overall curl of the electric field included)

Comment: @EPICTubeHD See the edit to my answer. It is (simply) piecing together a vector from its components. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector

Comment: Thx soo much for all the asistance! Also if u don't mind could u put the derivation for the limit equation of the curl of the electric field. That'll be great!

Comment: @EPICTubeHD It's a commonly employed definition of the curl. Read the wikipedia article.

Comment: maybe an even better technique would be to measure the voltage across smaller and smaller loops and then taking some regression to deduce a limit

Comment: @Nephente the dr in the integral is to be integrated with respect to the coordinate system we are working with yes?